# How to save changes back to XML file from a datasource?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

Here is the XML file:

```
<Test>
  <Code Layer='V' Colour='1'/>
  <Code Layer='W' Colour='1'/>
  <Code Layer='WE' Colour='1'/>
</Test>
```

My `Form` (**WinForm**) has a `DataGridView` on it and I have bound the view to my XML file:

```
private void GENIO_Code_Editor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml("d:\\MyFile.xml");
    dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
}
```

It works (note that example has more codes in the XML file):

[image: Example]

My problem is that, if I type in new values at the bottom (asterix row) these new additions are not getting updated in the XML file.

What step am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried saving the dataset using .WriteXML?

Comment: @dbasnett Turn your comment into an answer please as that is what I needed. If you add it as an answer I will accept and vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the dataset are not saved automatically.  To save the dataset use the .WriteXml method.

```
dataSet.WriteXml("d:\\MyFile.xml");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12536851)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - I did comment on the OP.

Comment: @dbasnett You forgot to reword it into a proper answer though. 